# How to find the label of a shape on a Powerpoint slide

Tags: vba, windows, powerpoint

Can someone please point me in the right direction to finding the label Powerpoint uses for each shape, active x control, etc...  I've researched till I'm blue in the face.  Here's what I'm talking about:

I have a very simple slideshow that asks a question in a text box.  Just below the question I placed an active x control text box to get the user's answer.  All I want to do is take the answer and append it to a text file.  Here's the code:

```
Public Sub WriteAnswerToFile(slideNum As Integer, shapeNum As String)

    Dim filePath As String
    Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim objFile As Variant

    filePath = "C:\Batch Files\Powerpoint\ButtonPushes\AnswerFile.txt"

    Const ForAppending = 8

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Batch Files\Powerpoint\ButtonPushes\AnswerFile.txt", ForAppending)

    objFile.WriteLine     (Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(slideNum).Shapes(shapeNum).TextFrame.TextRange)

    objFile.Close

End Sub
```

From each slide, I pass the slide number and the shape designator to the sub routine.  The shapeNum is a string because I found that it worked (no better reason than that) for me to pass something like "TextBox 1" as the param.  It all works absolutely great if I know the Shape(designator); as in Shape(TextBox1).  For the life of me I cannot figure out how to pass the text input by the user into the active x control text box.  I have no idea what the designator is.  The property sheet for the text input box calls it TextBox1.  The Code sheet calls it TextBox1.  When I pass that parameter, it prints the question I asked, not the answer, to my text file.  I don't know how to call the input text box in my code.

[image: Screenshot]

My code prints "How did you hear about us?" to my text file when my code runs with `Call WriteAnswerToFile(2, "TextBox 1")`.  I'm sure that textbox is called textbox 1; it's the first textbox on the slide.  I just don't know what Powerpoint labels the user input box.

If there is some sort of Powerpoint scripting or layout page that will define all the shapes in the slidewhow, I'd sure like to be pointed that direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to refer to the form part of the Object since this is not a normal shape.

```
objFile.WriteLine (Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(slideNum).Shapes(shapeNum).OLEFormat.Object.Text)
```

To clarify from your comment. I think that you have two "Text Box 1". One is "TextBox 1" (note the space) which is the normal textbox and the ActiveX control is "TextBox1" (no space).

If I create a new blank slide and first add a normal text box and then an ActiveX textbox and then run the following code:

```
For Each shp In Slide2.Shapes
    Debug.Print shp.Name
Next shp
```

The Immediate window will show the following:

```
TextBox 1
TextBox1
```

Comment: This solution worked exactly as you have it coded to print my user input box to file.  One very annoying problem solved.  Thank you!  It no longer pulls the question text.  I don't get the 'why?'.  I'll have to familiarize myself with the OLE function.  If `shapeNum` still = `TextBox1`, what makes `OLE` discard the text in the normal textbox and retrieve the text from the active x text box.  ~ Lots for me to learn.

Comment: Thank you much for the additional edit showing the `For / Next` loop.  You've solved my immediate problem and completely answered my original question.  This does give the label for every shape on a slide.  Obviously, I overlooked the space being the difference in the `TextBox1` labels.  I still wouldn't have known about the `Object` function without your help.  Even with the correct label, my `TextFrame.TextRange` function will not pull the text from the active x control.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

By chance I happened to stumble upon the simplest answer to my question of "finding the label Powerpoint uses for each shape, active x control, etc.."

I am using the Office 16 (Office 365) suite that contains Powerpoint and would not be certain this feature is avaiable to other versions.

On the `Home` tab in Powerpoint there is an `Editing` submenu that contains a `Select` function.  As pictured here:

[image: Powerpoint Home Tab]

When you click on `Select`, another submenu appears that shows a `Selection Pane` function.  If you click on that, the selction pane shows up on the right hand of the screen.  In that pane you will see all of the objects on the current slide and the names Powerpoint has given to each of them.

[image: Powerpoint Selection Pane]

It shows there, the discrepancy I was having with calling TextBox(Space)1 and TextBox(NoSpace)1.

This works to be much more expedient for me to grab the name of the shape I want to call in my VBS Scripts.

I am thankful; however, for the time and frustration @Diederik Sieburgh saved me in allowing me to move forward with my project as it is now 2 weeks later that I stumbled upon this information.